# PowerBI from multiple similar sources mismatch sessions without apparent reason

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi, google-analytics-api, powerbi-desktop

I'm very aware that my title isn't very "problem solving" oriented. However I' like to understand the issue I have and I hope that it might help others.

I'm connected to a Google Analytics view. I've created three different sources in Power BI from the same view:

Sources with:

1. date, sessions and source / medium dimension
2. date, sessions and a hit level custom dimension
3. date, sessions, hit level custom dimension and source / medium
4. date, sessions

Sources 1,2,4 return the same total amount of sessions (which match Google Analytics numbers) however the source 3 return only half of the sessions.

So I guess something is not working between the source / medium dimension and the custom dimension however I'd like to understand why.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: source 3 or source 4? Anyway post screenshot of your reports pleas

Comment: In Google Analytics the report of source 2 and 4 (in the second row of your image) gives the same result?

Comment: No. There is a small discrepancies here too but we can explain this one because I took the screenshot the 2 of October. I should have exclude this date. Or it is maybe only some sampling. I'm especially interested in the discrepancies of source 3

Comment: Have you checked that there is no sampling or for example rolled-up data for high-cardinality dimensions?

Comment: what do you mean by rolled-up data for high-cardinality dimensions?

Comment: I described it in this article: https://www.analyticstraps.com/valori-raggruppati-in-other-nei-report/